# How does AWS CDK determine if there is a dependency between constructs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'd like to understand how AWS CDK defines its dependency structure on a deeper level. For example. Consider an s3 bucket name that is referenced in two ways but where the value is the same in both scenarios:

```js
this.firelensBucket = new Bucket(this, 'FooBucket', {
    bucketName: `FooBucket-${props.stageName}`,
    // Other properties...
});
// later in another stack...
this.firelensContainer = this.service.taskDefinition.addFirelensLogRouter('FooFirelensContainer', {
    environment: {
        S3_BUCKET_NAME: this.firelensBucket.bucketName
    }
});
```

Versus

```js
const nameStr = `FooBucket-${props.stageName}`;
this.firelensBucket = new Bucket(this, 'FooBucket', {
    bucketName: nameStr,
    // Other properties...
});
// later in another stack...
this.firelensContainer = this.service.taskDefinition.addFirelensLogRouter('FooFirelensContainer', {
    environment: {
        S3_BUCKET_NAME: nameStr
    }
});
```

In both these scenarios the value is identical but accessed differently. Does CDK view these both the same way? More broadly, what exactly defines if a construct is a dependency or not?

Depending on the answer to the prior scenario, a quick followup question would be if something like this would be considered a dependency between stacks:

```js
this.firelensBucket = new Bucket(this, 'FooBucket', {
    bucketName: `FooBucket-${props.stageName}`,
    // Other properties...
});
const nameStr = this.firelensBucket.bucketName;
// later in another stack...
this.service.taskDefinition.addFirelensLogRouter('FooFirelensContainer', {
    environment: {
        S3_BUCKET_NAME: nameStr
    }
});
```